# wrapping component based on select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, jquery-select2

I am trying to integrate a wrapping component based on `select2`, taking as an example the same one that proves the official documentation of `vue.js` https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html the problem is that I need to use this component as a multiple select and pick up the values of those selected in an array. this is the link to reproduce the official example https://jsfiddle.net/d131Lebj/4989/, what changes should I make to obtain this?

Comment: Just add 'multiple' in the select?  https://jsfiddle.net/7sga5kLy/

Comment: Okay, but the problem is that I need to get the values of those selected in an array, for example my selected model should look like this: [1,2]

Comment: I don't know to do it in the right way of Vue.js but look this : https://jsfiddle.net/4wtqohxs/ 
Check the console. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: seems what you need is `vm.$emit('input', $(this).val())`, like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgwq1hb9/)

Comment: [JQuery Select2: offical API](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/retrieving-selections) should be `.select2('data')` or `.find(':selected')`